# Русификация винды

Tags: windows-7

Что нужно, чтобы русифицировать винду. Должны привезти ноут на польском - надо русский поставить. Надо скачать какой-то пакет или просто в ней выбрать а она сама скачает?
Если можно киньте ссылочку на пакет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это зависит от версии Windows. К примеру на Windows 7 Enterprise пакеты локализаций предлагает служба установки обновлений, а на Home Basic русификация не ставиться. Уточните, что за версия, т.к. Home Basic теоретически тоже можно локализовать, но не так просто, как Enterprise.

В случае с Home Basic необходимо выполнить следующее:

1. Т.к. официально Microsoft предоставляет пакеты локализаций только для Enterprise и Ultimate версий, то необходимо найти пакет для русификации в интернете самостоятельно (google выдает первые 5 ссылок на сайты, где можно скачать). Единственное замечание скачиваемый файл должен иметь расширение .cab, а не .exe или .msi.
2. Необходимо поместить скачанный пакет с русификацией на тот диск, куда установлена система и запомнить его местоположение, например C:\lp\.
3. Теперь необходимо создать папку для промежуточных операций, например C:\tmp\
4. Следующим шагом нужно загрузиться в консоль восстановления. Для этого нажимаем F8 после того, как будут показана информация BIOS, но до того, как появится сообщение о загрузке системы. Если таким образом не получается, то грузимся с установочного диска Windows.
5. После этого нужно еще раз нажать F8 и в появившемся меню выбрать пункт "Устранение неполадок компьютера".
6. Далее в появившемся графическом окне выбираем командную строку и загружаемся в нее.
7. Теперь воспользуемся утилитой DISM для установки языкового пакета:

   dism /image:D: /scratchDir:D:tmp /Add-Package /PackagePath:D:lp<файл_пакета>.cab
8. Делаем вновь установленный язык языком по умолчанию:

   dism /image:D: /Set-SKUIntlDefaults:ru-RU
9. Перезагружаемся.
10. В загруженной системе открываем командную строку и говорим загрузчику, чтобы он использовал русский язык

    bcdedit /set {current} locale ru-RU
11. Перезагружаемся еще раз, если что-то пошло не так, то опять грузимся в консоль восстановления и выставляем языком по умолчанию прежний.

**P.S.** Обращаю внимание на то, что в примере, который я привел нет путаницы между дисками C: и D:. Это не ошибка. По умолчанию при установке Windows создает скрытый раздел (около 100мб) для своих нужд, который в консоли восстановления определяется, как C:, соответственно все диски смещаются на один, т.е. C: становится D: и т.д.

Comment: Home Basic(